# Responsive site: How to make the image/text in columns on desktop but not column on mobile

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, responsive, responsive-images

I'm new to coding and I'm making a personal homepage for an HTML/CSS assignment. For the about page, I want the text in 1 column and image in another column on the desktop version, but on mobile, the image on top and text on bottom. I was able to get the columns to appear as I like on the desktop version, but the problem is that they stay in columns on the mobile version too. Is there any way for it to stay the way they are on the desktop version, but get the image to go on top of the text instead of next to it on the mobile version? Thank you!

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
.header{
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(images/banner.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav a{      
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
}
nav a:hover{
    color:#f44336;
    transition: .4s;
}
.nav-links{
        flex:1;
        text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li{
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: relative;
}
.nav-links ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 13px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#f44336;
    transition: .4s;
}
.text-box{
        width: 90%;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        text-align: center;
}
.text-box h1{
    font-size: 54px;
}
.text-box p{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

nav .fa{
        display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
    nav{
        display: flex;
        padding: 4% 8%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
        .text-box h1{
                font-size: 14px;
        }
        .text-box p{
                font-size: 11px;
        }
        .nav-links ul li {
            display: block;
        }
        .nav-links{
            position: absolute;
            background: #f44336;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 200px;
            top: 0;
            right: -200px;
            text-align: left;
            z-index: 2;
            transition: 1s;
        }
        nav ul li a:hover{
            color:#12161d;
            transition: .4s;
        }
        nav .fa{
            display: block;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 22px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .nav-links ul{
            padding: 30px;
        }
}

/*--footer--*/

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.icons .fa{
        color: #808080;
        margin: 0 13px;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px 0;
    }

/*--about page--*/

.sub-header{
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(images/background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
.sub-header h1{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.about-us{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.about-col{
    flex-basis:48%;
    padding: 30px 2px;
}
.about-col img{
    width: 100%;
}

.about-col h1{
    padding-top: 0;
}
.about-col p{
    padding: 15px 0 25px;
}
.row {
   display:flex;
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
            .about-col h1{
                font-size: 14px;
        }
        .about-col p{
                font-size: 10px;
        }
        .about-col{
    flex-basis:48%;
    padding: 20px 5px;
}
.about-col img{
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Personal Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/012219d900.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.text-box{
background-color: transparent;
color: #FFF;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="sub-header">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">AMANDA YEE</a>
                <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                  <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
            </nav>
            <h1>ABOUT</h1>
</section>

<!--about content-->
<section class="about-us">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="about-col">
            <h1>About Me</h1>
            <p>Born and raised in the Bay</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-col">
        <img src="images/about.jpg" alt="girl smiling">
    </div>
</div>

</section>



<!--Footer-->

<section class="footer">
    <div class="icons">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </div>
</section>






<!--Javascript for Toggle Menu-->
    <script>
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
        
        function showMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to change position of elements is to use `flex-direction`. I usually create a parent container and add `display: flex;`. By default flex is row oriented. When I need elements to be in one column I create a media with `flex-direction: column;` for container. Here is a sample

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Just some styles, not important */
.element {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">Element one</div>
  <div class="element">Element two</div>
</div>
```